# Stop Current Sound when another is pressed React Native Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Im having trouble trying to stop the current playing sound when another Sound is pressed without having to pause the current Sound in react Native Expo. Note: I can pause and play the Sound perfectly. So basically like a normal music player if that is overlapping when pressing another song.

```
const SampleTrack = {uri:'https://firebasestorage.googleapisro-b97ec.appspot.com/o/song%201.mp3?a9'}

const FirstP = () => { 
  const [Loaded, SetLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const [Loading, SetLoading] = React.useState(false);
  
  const sound = React.useRef(new Audio.Sound());
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    LoadAudio();
  }, []);
 
  
   const PlayAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === false) {
          sound.current.playAsync();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  const PauseAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === true) {
          sound.current.pauseAsync();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  const LoadAudio = async () => {
    SetLoading(true);
    const checkLoading = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (checkLoading.isLoaded === false) {
      try {
        const result = await sound.current.loadAsync(SampleTrack, {}, true);
        if (result.isLoaded === false) {
          SetLoading(false);
          console.log('Error in Loading Audio');
        } else {
          SetLoading(false);
          SetLoaded(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        SetLoading(false);
      }
    } else {
      SetLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

if anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Presumably you have a list of songs or something like that, but you haven't included it, so it's hard to make good recommendations. I'd store audio state in the parent view of all of the individual list items so that it's easy to play/pause when a new item is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete Audio Player with Play/Pause/Load/Next/Previous feature.

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/playing_pausing-music)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';

const Tracks = [
  {
    id: 0,
    track: require('./Roses.m4a'),
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    track: require('./Poison.m4a'),
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    track: require('./Alone.m4a'),
  },
];

export default function App() {
  const [Loaded, SetLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const [Loading, SetLoading] = React.useState(false);
  const [CurrentSong, SetCurrentSong] = React.useState(Tracks[0]);
  const sound = React.useRef(new Audio.Sound());

  React.useEffect(() => {
    LoadAudio();

    return () => Unload();
  }, [CurrentSong]);

  const Unload = async () => {
    await sound.current.unloadAsync();
  };

  const PlayAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === false) {
          sound.current.playAsync();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const PauseAudio = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === true) {
          sound.current.pauseAsync();
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const LoadAudio = async () => {
    SetLoaded(false);
    SetLoading(true);
    const checkLoading = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (checkLoading.isLoaded === false) {
      try {
        const result = await sound.current.loadAsync(
          CurrentSong.track,
          {},
          true
        );
        if (result.isLoaded === false) {
          SetLoading(false);
          console.log('Error in Loading Audio');
        } else {
          SetLoading(false);
          PlayAudio();
          SetLoaded(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        SetLoading(false);
      }
    } else {
      SetLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const NextSong = () => {
    if (CurrentSong.id === Tracks[Tracks.length - 1].id) {
      SetCurrentSong(Tracks[0]);
    } else {
      SetCurrentSong(Tracks[CurrentSong.id + 1]);
    }
  };

  const PrevSong = () => {
    if (CurrentSong.id === 0) {
      SetCurrentSong(Tracks[Tracks.length - 1]);
    } else {
      SetCurrentSong(Tracks[CurrentSong.id - 1]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.AudioPLayer}>
        {Loading === true ? (
          <ActivityIndicator size={'small'} color={'red'} />
        ) : (
          <>
            <Button title="Play Song" onPress={PlayAudio} />
            <Button title="Pause Song" onPress={PauseAudio} />
            <Text>Currently Playing : {CurrentSong.id}</Text>
            <Button title="Next Song" onPress={NextSong} />
            <Button title="Previous Song" onPress={PrevSong} />
          </>
        )}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  AudioPLayer: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you but can you also help me with linking each sound with different buttons. Im trying to use them as props but nothing is helping. Im trying to do something like this.<TouchableOpacity  onPress={PlayAudio.id[1]}>
 <FontAwesome name= 'play' size={30} color={"white"}/>
</TouchableOpacity>

Comment: Check working Example snack again to see the result that you asked. I've updated that

Comment: Thanks man for all your help. Im still alittle confused on how to match a certain button with any song of my choosing. Like If i want to have each song id matched to its own playAudio button. Like how a playlist has different songs and each song button has its own sound.

Comment: I sorta figured a way to do it but I dont think its the correct way to do it. Its Also giving me a warning to change the else section so its not identical but it doesnt work then                                                                                                         
   ```const ThirdSong = () => {
    if (CurrentSong.id === Tracks[Tracks.length - 1].id) {
      SetCurrentSong(Tracks[3]);
    }  else {
      SetCurrentSong(Tracks[3]);}
  };```